# Existing docker image not being detected for docker container creation

Tags: docker, minikube

Currently has following docker images locally:

```
(tts_test) root@e2e-100-17:~/Documents/tritonTTSdeployment# docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
customtritonimagetts                      latest          a34706205a9a   5 minutes ago    17.7GB
tritonserver                              latest          19817c37bb25   12 minutes ago   8.81GB
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.26.1         deb04688c4a3   11 days ago      134MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.26.1         655493523f60   11 days ago      56.3MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.26.1         e9c08e11b07f   11 days ago      124MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.26.1         46a6bb3c77ce   11 days ago      65.6MB
registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.6-0         fce326961ae2   2 months ago     299MB
nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver               22.10-py3-min   8bc805049606   3 months ago     6.72GB
nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver               22.10-py3       486d7ee640ad   3 months ago     13.5GB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9             e6f181688397   3 months ago     744kB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.9.3          5185b96f0bec   8 months ago     48.8MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.6             6270bb605e12   17 months ago    683kB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner   v5              6e38f40d628d   22 months ago    31.5MB
```

Command to create container:

```
docker run -t customtritonimagetts
```

Still after trying to run the following command to create docker container, it's not creating the docker container and throwing following error:

```
Unable to find image 'customtritonimagetts:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for customtritonimagetts, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

earlier i was trying to configure Minikube and might have caused some issues with docker images creation and image registry. What can be possible issues!

[NOTE: there was slight typo error which i corrected and the issue still persist]

Comment: There is a typo, either in the image already existing, or the one used in docker run command, your pick. (customtrit( I )onimagetts)

Comment: Maybe a typo error `customtritonimagetts` vs `customtritionimagetts`?

Comment: Now that you have edited away the typo, does the error still persist?

Comment: @derpirscher yes

Comment: Can you try running `docker run -t a34706205a9a`? ie run the image by id?

Comment: And I'm not sure whether image names can contain whitespaces, but you can run `docker images --format="--{{.Repository}}--"` which will list all image names enclosed in `--` so you can make sure there is no whitespace in the name

Comment: @derpirscher tried above suggestion (run by id) which is not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the repository is public, this error means that the docker image you are trying to pull is private.Only logged users with permissions may pull the image.

Try the troubleshooting steps:

1- docker logout

2- docker login --username=YOURUSERNAME Enter password when asked

3- docker pull repositoryName"/"imageName[:tag]

if "tag" is not included the default value will be "latest". Then check the images by docker images command to check if it's been pulled. After pulling it you can make the repository private again.

Comment: The docker image is alread pulled ... It already shows up in the output of `docker images` And no, the error doesn necessarily mean that the repository is private. It can also mean that the image just doesn't exist ...   Quoting the error message: *"repository **does not exist** or may require 'docker login'"*